# Mongodb get count() of CommandCursor

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I'm performing a search with this aggregate and would like to get my total count (to deal with my pagination).

```
results = mongo.db.perfumes.aggregate(
    [
        {"$match": {"$text": {"$search": db_query}}},
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "users",
                "localField": "author",
                "foreignField": "username",
                "as": "creator",
            }
        },
        {"$unwind": "$creator"},
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "perfumeName": "$name",
                "perfumeBrand": "$brand",
                "perfumeDescription": "$description",
                "date_updated": "$date_updated",
                "perfumePicture": "$picture",
                "isPublic": "$public",
                "perfumeType": "$perfume_type",
                "username": "$creator.username",
                "firstName": "$creator.first_name",
                "lastName": "$creator.last_name",
                "profilePicture": "$creator.avatar",
            }
        },
        {"$sort": {"perfumeName": 1}},
    ]
)
```

How could I get the count of `results` in my route so I can pass it to my template?

I cannot use `results.count()` as it is a CommandCursor.

Help please? Thank you!!

Comment: I believe you would need to retrieve all of the results and then look at how many you got.

Comment: Well but I'd need to do that in the route without extinguishing the cursor...

Comment: If you want the count only, you need to adjust the query you are sending to be a count query. Otherwise after you retrieve all of the results you'll have the count.

Comment: In the end I sorted it by creating another (smaller) aggregation only for the count. What I wanted to do was to count AND get also the cursor with all the information to iterate on in the template, all in the same aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Using `len` method to return no.of elements in an array would be easier but if you still wanted an aggregation query to return count and actual docs at the same time then try using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) or `$group` :

**Query 1 :**

```
 {
    $facet: {
      docs: [ { $match: {} } ], // passes all docs into an array field
      count: [ { $count: "count" } ] // counts no.of docs
    }
  },
  /** re-create count field from array of one object to just a number */
  {
    $addFields: { count: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$count.count", 0 ] } }
  }
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/81zaMo0n03S)

**Query 2 :**

```
 /** Group all docs without any condition & push all docs into an array field & count no.of docs flowing through iteration using `$sum` */
{
   $group: { _id: "", docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }, count: { $sum: 1 } }
}
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TqlUnMxfv2s)

**Note :**

Add one of these queries at the end of your current aggregation pipeline and remember if there are no docs after `$match` or `$unwind` stages then first query would not have `count` field but has `docs : []` but second query will just return `[]`, code it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [CommandCursor](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.3.1/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html#pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor)'s docs, it does not support `count()`

You can use the [`length`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#length) filter in jinja template.

```html
{{ results | length }}
```

I hope the above helps.

Comment: Thanks! But in fact I should be able to assign the count to a variable in order to pass it in my route to the configuration of flask-paginate. I actually sorted it by creating a second aggregation. If there is a better solution I'd be happy to know! I bet there should be a way to get the results AND the count using the same aggregation...